# Texture repeating and clamping in shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have the following fragment and vertex shader, in which I repeat a texture:

```
//Fragment
vec2 texcoordC = gl_TexCoord[0].xy;
texcoordC *= 10.0;
texcoordC.x = mod(texcoordC.x, 1.0);
texcoordC.y = mod(texcoordC.y, 1.0);
texcoordC.x = clamp(texcoordC.x, 0.0, 0.9);
texcoordC.y = clamp(texcoordC.y, 0.0, 0.9);
vec4 texColor = texture2D(sampler, texcoordC);
gl_FragColor = texColor;

//Vertex
gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
colorC = gl_Color.r;
gl_Position = ftransform();
```

ADDED: After this process, I fetch the texture coordinates and use a texture pack:

```
vec4 textureGet(vec2 texcoord) {
    // Tile is 1.0/16.0 part of texture, on x and y
    float tileSp = 1.0 / 16.0;

    vec4 color = texture2D(sampler, texcoord);
    // Get tile x and y by red color stored
    float texTX = mod(color.r, tileSp);
    float texTY = color.r - texTX;
    texTX /= tileSp;
    // Testing tile
    texTX = 1.0 - tileSp;
    texTY = 1.0 - tileSp;

    vec2 savedC = color.yz;
    // This if else statement can be ignored. I use time to move the texture. Seams show without this as well.
    if (color.r > 0.1) {
        savedC.x = mod(savedC.x + sin(time / 200.0 * (color.r * 3.0)), 1.0);
        savedC.y = mod(savedC.y + cos(time / 200.0 * (color.r * 3.0)), 1.0);
    } else {
        savedC.x = mod(savedC.x + time * (color.r * 3.0) / 1000.0, 1.0);
        savedC.y = mod(savedC.y + time * (color.r * 3.0) / 1000.0, 1.0);
    }
    vec2 texcoordC = vec2(texTX + savedC.x * tileSp, texTY + savedC.y * tileSp);

    vec4 res = texture2D(texturePack, texcoordC);
    return res;
}
```

I have some troubles with showing seams (of 1 pixel it seems) however. If I leave out texcoord *= 10.0 no seams are shown (or barely), if I leave it in they appear. I clamp the coordinates (even tried lower than 1.0 and bigger than 0.0) to no avail. I strongly have the feeling it is a rounding error somewhere, but I have no idea where. *ADDED: Something to note is that in the actual case I convert the texcoordC x and y to 8 bit floats. I think the cause lies here; I added another shader describing this above.*

The case I show is a little more complicated in reality, so there is no use for me to do this outside the shader(!). I added the previous question which explains a little about the case.

EDIT: As you can see the natural texture span is divided by 10, and the texture is repeated (10 times). The seams appear at the border of every repeating texture. I also added a screenshot. The seams are the very thin lines (~1pixel). The picture is a cut out from a screenshot, not scaled. The repeated texture is 16x16, with 256 subpixels total. [image: Seams]

EDIT: This is a followup question of: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440910/precision-loss-with-mod-in-glsl), although all necessary info should be included here.

[image]
Last picture has no time added.

[image: The UV's coordinates as green,blue and red as the texturetile channel.]

[image: Another without red]

Comment: `mod(value, 1.0)` is going to yield `[0, 1.0[`, so `clamp(value, 0.0, 0.9)` is always going to introduce a discontinuity.

Comment: I added the clamp later; it wouldn't cause the seams either I'd presume.

Comment: How are you setting up the texture coordinates for the object you're drawing?

Comment: What do you mean by "seams"? Where are you seeing these seams? What are you trying to render with this?

Comment: @user1118321: Texture coordinates are always 0..1. As you can see the repeating works.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I added a screenshot showing the seams.

Comment: I think you might be having an issue with sampling. At least with the atlas, but perhaps also with reading back your previously stored UV coords. I can't see where you account for the half-texel offset when tiling within the atlas, and there's no border, so you may get some bleeding. And if there isn't perfect 1:1 sampling with the UV read-back from the first pass, you'll get the same issue you had when trying to do the tiling per-vertex, but at a smaller scale. I'd perhaps debug by rendering out the stored UVs, and checking that they look correct.

Comment: @JasonD When I view the UV's (saved to PNG), all looks fine.

Comment: What's your setting on the actual texture? Clamp, repeat, fixed color?

Comment: I added a slice of the UV output.

Comment: @Mario On the actual texture I have a fixed color.

Comment: Any chance this is what you're seeing? It seems to be the last tile in that row after all. Or does it happen no matter which tile you want to draw?

Comment: Might be my browser, but it looks like you're filtering the UVs.

Comment: @JasonD The UV's coordinates as green(x),blue(y) and red as the texturetile channel. The latter has red set to zero.

Comment: @Mario It happens no matter which tile I draw.

Comment: @JasonD I do get some bleeding sometimes, but it seems to disappear when I don't use the time-part of the shader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the render of the UV coordinates, they are being filtered, which will cause the same issue as in your previous question, but on a smaller scale. What is happening is that by sampling the UV coordinate texture at a point between two discontinuous values (i.e. two adjacent points where the texture coordinates wrapped), you get an interpolated value which isn't in the right part of the texture. Thus the boundary between texture tiles is a mess of pixels from all over that tile.

[image]

You need to get the mapping 1:1 between screen pixels and the captured UV values. Using nearest sampling might get you some of the way there, but it should be possible to do without using that, if you have the right texture and pixel coordinates in the first place.

Secondly, you may find you get bleeding effects due to the way you are doing the texture atlas lookup, as you don't account for the way texels are sampled. This will be amplified if you use any mipmapping. Ideally you need a border, and possibly some massaging of the coordinates to account for half-texel offsets. However I don't think that's the main issue you're seeing here.

Comment: I didn't notice the filtering, I thought there was none. However, I did came up with the same before, using nearest instead of linear and it didn't help. But your answer does point me in the right direction, so I'm going to look into this more. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Solved it, apparently I didn't set nearest at the right place.

Comment: I solved half texel lookup, by multiplying by 11.0 instead of 10.0 in the first fragment shader.